# How to Write jQuery Only if a Child Div has a Class

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-selectors, selector

I have a menu that will be generated in php that will have the possibility of having two different child divs within it. Long story short, the php will add a div with a class name of "showBubbles" within the "li", and/or another div with the class of "hideLogo." I need to execute one function if "showBubbles" div is present, and another function if "hideLogo" is present. How can I do this on mouse hover? 
The structure looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#"><img src="imagePlaceholder" /></a>
    <div class="showBubbles"></div>
    <div class="hideLogo"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And do you need to execute both functions if both divs are present too?

Comment: yes, both functions need to fire if only one or both are present

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not tested but this should do the trick.

```
$('ul').on('mouseover', 'li', function(e)
{
    if($(this).children('div').hasClass('showBubbles'))
    {
        // Execute code for showBubbles div
    }
    else
    {
        // Execute code if 'showBubbles' is not present
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

inside the hover callback function, you can use the following code:

```
var showBubbles = $("li div.showBubbles").length;
if(showBubbles > 0){
   // first function here
}

var hideLogo = $("li div.hideLogo").length;
if(hideLogo > 0){
   // second function here
}
```

Comment: do I need to put a "this" in there?

Comment: this is the same as other answers here, except that I wrote the pattern all at once `li div.hideLogo`, but others selected `li` and in the callback, where `this` refers to the `li` they selected the rest of the pattern.
the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a div with a certain class by trying to select it with jQuery, then checking the `length` of the returned jQuery object. For example, for `showBubbles`:

```
var showBubblesExists = $('li .showBubbles').length > 0;
```

I believe this should point you to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
var sb = 0, hb = 0;
$('li').hover(function () {
   sb = $('.showBubbles', this).length;
   hb = $('.hideLogo', this).length;

   if (sb) {  /*function for sb*/ }
   if (hb) { /*function for hb*/ }

}, function () {

   if (sb) {
     //function for sb 
     sb = 0;
   }
   if (hb) { 
     //function for hb 
     hb = 0;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').on('mouseover', 'li', function() {

   $(this).find('div.showBubbles').length && showBubbles(); //calls showBubbles()

   $(this).find('div.hideLogo').length && hideLogo(); //calls hideLogo()

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

***JS CODE***

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    if($(this).find('.showBubbles')){
       showBubbles();
    }
    if($(this).find('.hideLogo')){
       hideLogo();
    }
});

function showBubbles(){
  alert('showBubbles response');
}

function hideLogo(){
  alert('hideLogo response');
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/AExLu/16/)**

Comment: @TripsLeft is the code working? if modification needed please inform.